# Random selection of weighted items

Tags: arrays, sorting, activerecord, random

My model TicketBuyer columns include ticket_buyer name and number_of_tickets purchased. I want to randomly select a winning ticket. I think my preference is to create another model (SelectTable) that has the ticket_buyer name replicated over the number of rows equal to the number_of_tickets purchased, thereby giving equal weight to each record. I can then just run a simple sort and pick the first record in the new table. I am having trouble auto creating the table with the correct number of rows for each ticket_buyer. Of course, there may be a more eloquent/ efficient way to do this as well. Advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If speed isn't a problem you can do it without creating any extra data structures.

- Find the maximum number_of_tickets bought by anyone
- Randomly select a ticket buyer
- Do another draw, with a number_of_tickets / max_number_of_tickets chance of them becoming the winner
- If they fail the second draw, randomly select another ticket buyer and repeat the process until someone wins

Unless there is some crazy distribution like one person buys a million tickets and everyone else buys one, this shouldn't take too long.

Pseudo-code:

```
 max_tickets = max(table:number_of_tickets)
 while true do:
     // select a random buyer
     buyer = select random row from table

     // assume random(n) returns an integer number from 0 to n - 1 inclusive:
     if random(max_tickets) < buyer.number_of_tickets then
          return buyer   // we have a winner
 end
```

Comment: I like it! Let's give a name: it's something like [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). The alternatives (which are more complex) are listed here: [on wiki (part: finite discrete distributions)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling), where i recommend the [alias-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method) if speed is important. This will need additional work though.

Comment: Thank you.  I have not seen this approach before but looks good.  Any example code would be much appreciated.

Comment: I failed to mention that I am writing this in Rails.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with Rails. I didn't realise the question was specific to Rails when I answered it.

Comment: @sasha I think it's rejection sampling with a discrete distribution.